# Mysql again, group by and display rest of rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have table:

id, day, user, value, active

And now i get
SELECT day from ppl GROUP BY user

but! i want to get all days in one row, not only one

for example

day: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...
user: myusername

is it possible?

Yep,

```
SELECT
     user,
     GROUP_CONCAT(day) day
 FROM ppl
 GROUP BY 1;
```

Is answer for my question, but i've got next, last

Here is result of query
http://screenshooter.net/0562655/24_05_2012__22_37_09

how to change

```
row 3 from 8,9,10 to 8-10
row 5 from 21,22,23,24,28,29,30 to 21-24,28-30
row 6 from 17,21,22,23,24,25 to 17,21-25
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT
     user,
     GROUP_CONCAT(day) day
 FROM ppl
 GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: LOOOOOL, so easy :F, why group by 1? 1 is user? 2 is day, 3 don't exist?