# Select first and last row from group_concat when grouping sortable days

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Referring to my previous questions about the group concat
[Mysql again, group by and display rest of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744778/mysql-again-group-by-and-display-rest-of-rows)

i need to get first and last day from that query

for example

```
row 3 from 8,9,10 to first collumn 8, last collumn 10
row 5 from 21,22,23,24,28,29,30 to first collumn 21, last collumn 30
row 6 from 17,21,22,23,24,25 to first collumn 17 last collumn 25

SUBSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(DAY),-1) as fl
```

BUT it gives me last char, and there are few rows with 1 or 2 chars for example

```
1,2,3,22
1,3,6,3
```

In first example it gaves me 2, not 22 :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't waste your time trying to parse the first and last off of `GROUP_CONCAT()`.  Instead, just stick the `MIN()` and `MAX()` together with `CONCAT()`.

```
SELECT 
  user,
  CONCAT(MIN(DAY)), ',', MAX(DAY)) AS f1
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY user
```

Comment: do the min and max behave like the "first" and "last" or do they behave like their name sounds like?

Comment: @Jus12 They are [the aggregate `MIN()/MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) so they are as they sound, the least and greatest values per `user` group.

Comment: I like this, but the solution is very specific if the data is arranged by date and the question seems more generic "select first and last row from group concat". Ideally there should be a way to select the first and last elements without sorting. Is there anything like that?

Comment: No,  except for performing string operations on the concatenation as in the other answer. Because aggregate functions are applied only once per group per `SELECT` level, to get the first or last you would need some additional aggregation, wrapping it in a subquery to retrieve the min/max, or subqueries to `ORDER BY/LIMIT` and extract only one row. All these solutions are ugly. I'll edit the question title to make it more specific to the use case.

Comment: @Jus12 You should ask a new question if you are looking for a more generic use case

Answer (score 13):

Another option (besides Michael's solution) is to use the SUBSTRING_INDEX:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)
```

with

```
count = 1
```

you get the first day,

with

```
count=-1
```

you get the last one

Comment: This works and I thank you for it. However, I can't believe there is no way to do that without concatenating and string to then split it. That is a lot of string manipulation for something that was already at some point an array.